# R: modify sequence function

Tags: r, seq

I have generated a sequence which I call `a` and need a function of function `a` which I call `b` to modify function `a` by starting from the first element of function `a` and stop at a specified nth element

```
l<-3
k<-1
n<-1:10
a<-starts<-seq(1, length(n), by=1)
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

I need a function that will use function `a` that will generate elements that start with the first elements of function `a` and stop at `length(n) - l + 1` in this case it is 8.

**tried this**

```
b<-starts - l + 1
```

and got

```
# [1]  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
```

**I need**

```
 # [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
```

Comment: Why do you say that a is a function? In your code `a` is just a vector. So `b` isn't really a call, it's just an assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create the desired sequence by

```
a[1L] : (length(n) - l + 1)
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Or similarly by using `seq` function

```
seq(a[1L], (length(n) - l + 1))
```